# Explanation of results of JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I've been using JQuery selectors for a while, but I am unclear about many aspects of what exactly using a JQuery selector does.

Such as, when I have an html element like this -

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

And run a JQuery statement like this -

```
var myVar = $('#myDiv');
```

After the JQuery statement is executed, I inspect the variable I see the following -

```
x.fn.x.init[1]
   > context: document
   length: 1
   selector: "#myDiv"
   > __proto__: Object[0]
```

`context` and `__proto__` can be expanded to show lists of methods and properties.
Can someone explain what `x.fn.x.init[1]` is? What's "x", what's "fn", etc.? And what is meant by `context: document`, and `__proto__: Object[0]` are and why they are getting set the way they are with all the methods and properties and such?

Comment: `id="#myDiv"` is wrong, leave out the '#'.

Comment: you sure that it has `[0]` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. I removed the #.

Comment: Yes, Joki, it has [0]. This question is not about a bug, I'm just trying to understand what all the things displayed means. Like what is - "x.fn.x.init[0]"?

Comment: It's accessing the value of the property `0` of the `x.fn.x.init` object.

Comment: When you call $('#myDiv') you call the jquery constructor on that dom element, __proto__ contains all of the methods that you can call on that element. Expand them they are pretty self explanatory....

Comment: It's a jquery object. When you run the selector it will create a jquery object that holds the result(s). Explaining all the individual bits of said object is a broad question and to answer that you should start with the jquery docs.

Comment: Why not have a look at the [jquery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src)? `$()` is just a function that returns an object. Have a look at the [core.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) file specifically.